# Header file gives error

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a UI in Qt and need to have input.h included in spel.h, when I use input.h in my mainwindow.h everything works but I also need him in my spel.h and then QT gives these errors:

```
expected ')' before '*' token Input.h R 9   
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Form' with no type Input.h R 13   
expected ';' before '*' token Input.h R13
```

Me and my friend are searching for 2 hours right now and still don't see why it's giving errors. Include guards everything is okay.

Input.h:

```
#ifndef INPUT_H
    #define INPUT_H
    #include "form.h"

    class Input
    {

    public:
        Input(Form * pointer):speler(pointer){};
        int geefGoederenPopup(void);

    private:
        Form * speler;
    };


#endif // INPUT_H
```

Comment: What is form.h? Also, please put the code in your actual question -- not a link to a pastebin site.

Comment: Can you show us `form.h`? Using forward declarations may solve your immediate problem but I suspect problems with your Form class declaration.

Comment: My money is on you forgetting the semicolon at the end of the Form class declaration, but until we see the form.h file it's hard to say.

Comment: The form.h file looks good (http://pastebin.com/teV0yZ2N); I have deleted my answer as it won't solve your problem.

Comment: I also don't see the problem why Qt is giving me that error. I only have the error when including in spel.h.. Do you need spel.h too?

Comment: Won't hurt.  You should edit your question and paste all relevant code within it.

Comment: Do you run your form.h through moc.exe? If so, what do you do with the result?

Comment: In any case you have a superfluous semicolon following the empty constructor definition.

Comment: Does `form.h` include `input.h`? If so, you have a cyclic include problem that can't be solved with an include guard. But in any case, you can forward declare `Form` instead of including its header file.

Comment: @Dabbler Good point about the cyclic dependencies, why not put it in an answer instead?

Comment: It's only a hypothesis at this point :-)

Answer (score 2):

Does `form.h` include `input.h`? If so, you have a cyclic include problem that can't be solved with an include guard. But in any case, you can forward declare Form instead of including its header file. Actually I'm pretty sure that will solve the problem.

Comment: No form.h doesn't include input.h. And declaring the class ahead doesn't work either.

Comment: `mainwindow.h` includes `input.h`, which includes `form.h`, which includes ... `mainwindow.h`. No cycle uh ? Beside, why including `mainwindow.h` in `form.h`, maybe you didn't paste the whole code or is it actually useless ?